# Iterating through container - when to use reference and when not

Tags: c++, c++11

In the code below, we don't dereference `y` (it is error in fact), but we do dereference `z`. Can someone explain why so?

```
 #include <iostream>  
 #include <vector>  


int main()   
{  
std::vector <int> x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

 for( auto y : x ) 
     std::cout << y << " ";  

std::cout<<std::endl;

for(auto z = x.begin();z!=x.end();++z)
    std::cout<<*z<<" ";
}
```

Comment: because an iterator looks like a pointer.

Comment: Because `z` is an iterator, and `y` is not -- `y` is a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second construct is an explicit way of loop iteration via iterators.

The first one is a syntactic sugar. You can read about it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for. It can be seen there that the construct is transformed into something like:

```
auto && __range = range_expression ; 
auto __begin = begin_expr ;
auto __end = end_expr ;
for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
    range_declaration = *__begin; 
    loop_statement 
}
```

The key place for understanding is **range_declaration = *__begin**. Here range_declaration is **y** and it is assigned from real iterator.

Answer (score 1):

> In the code below, we don't dereference `y` (it is error in fact), but
>   we do dereference `z`. Can someone explain why so?

We don't because the compiler does.

---

The [range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for): `auto y : x` also uses the `begin` and `end` functions, and it dereferences the iterators for you. It is equivalent to the following syntax:

```
auto && __range = range_expression;     // reference that we'll get to use
auto __begin = begin_expr;              // get iterator
auto __end = end_expr;
for(; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    range_declaration = *__begin;       // dereference iterator
    loop_statement
}
```

The iterators in turn perform the dereferencing by having overloaded the `*` operator to return a reference.

---

So in the question the second part actually does exactly what the *range based for* does for you 'behind the scenes'.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using two different types. `auto y : x` is saying that `y` will be the actual element itself (`1`, `2` etc), whereas `auto z = x.begin()` is saying that `z` will be nn `iterator`, which you need to dereference to get the actual value.

You should simply prefer to use the first, because the code is shorter and more easily readable.